# Can AndroidDeveloper do anything like XCode's // MARK: - ...?

Tags: xcode, android-studio

One of the features I use a bunch in larger code bodies in XCode is the ability to delineate/label blocks of functionality with `// MARK:` comments. These get used by the IDE to label things in the menus. I'm porting an app to AndroidStudio/Kotlin, and really missing this. Is there anything like this? I've found the `Structure` view, but I don't see any hints that comments influence it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same but you can do:

```
//region RegionName

    ... code ...

//endregion
```

and you'll be able to fold this section of code.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I should probably clarify that I'm doing Kotlin. Maybe it works in Java, but not Kotlin?